# Size of the array and values set to the array elements if no argument is given in PHP array() function

Tags: php, arrays

We can create an array $cars as:

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
```

But, what if we create simply as:

```
$cars = array();
```

What will become the size of the array by the second statement if we don't explicitly specify the parameters in array() function and what values are set to the array elements if the array is created?

Comment: You are simply resetting the array by the second statement with no values.

Comment: worth reading:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would generate an empty array having 0 elements. see `echo count($cars)`

If you asking for memory occupied, it would occupy `224 bytes`, you can check like this

```
$startMemory = memory_get_usage();
$cars= array();
echo memory_get_usage() - $startMemory, ' bytes';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply test using `var_dump(count($cars));` Returns int 0

If you var_dump `var_dump($cars);` Returns array (size=0)
  empty

Answer (score 0):

It will be empty array having length = 0;

For adding elements:

```
$cars[] = "Mitsubishi";
```

For getting length:

```
count($cars);
```